# Returning String from a do-catch statement

Tags: swift, do-catch

I was trying to translate the code from swift 2 to swift 4 and came across this error

> Errors thrown from here are not handled

So I did this but now it tells me to return a string. Any idea how to do this?

```
func formatSentence(sentence:String) -> String
{
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\W+", options: .caseInsensitive)
        let modifiedString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: sentence, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0,length: sentence.count), withTemplate: "")

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    //I tried adding it here the return modifiedString but gives me error
}
```

This is what the original function looks like

```
func formatSentence(sentence:String) -> String
{
    let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\W+", options: .caseInsensitive)//NSRegularExpression(pattern:"\\W+", options: .CaseInsensitive, error: nil)
    let modifiedString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: sentence, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0,length: sentence.count), withTemplate: "")

    return modifiedString
}
```

Comment: You literally just return a string: `return modifiedString`

Comment: @vadian yeah but it’s not letting me

Comment: what does it say ?

Comment: What do you mean? Did you try adding that line of code?

Comment: You might need to init the string like var response = "" outside of the do/catch and return it out side of it. You can then assign the response = modifiedString or response = error to return the error in case its throw.

Comment: @vadian yes, it says `Use of unresolved identifier 'modifiedString'`

Comment: what happens when u do this `return regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: sentence, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0,length: sentence.count), withTemplate: "")`

Comment: remove the `let modifiedString` since you don't really need that

Comment: @vadian i did still same problem unresloved 'regex'

Comment: @AB3760 Please, take a look on my answer below.

Comment: OP, see my answer, and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends upon how you want to handle the error condition. There are a few options:

1. You could make it return `String?`, where `nil` means there was an error:

   ```
   func formatSentence(_ sentence: String) -> String? {
       do {
           let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\W+", options: .caseInsensitive)
           let range = NSRange(sentence.startIndex..., in: sentence)
           return regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: sentence, range: range, withTemplate: "")
       } catch {
           print(error)
           return nil
       }
   }
   ```

   And then you'd do something like:

   ```
   guard let sentence = formatSentence(string) else { 
       // handle error here
       return
   }

   // use `sentence` here
   ```
2. You could define your function as one that `throws` the error if it encounters one:

   ```
   func formatSentence(_ sentence: String) throws -> String {
       let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\W+", options: .caseInsensitive)
       let range = NSRange(sentence.startIndex..., in: sentence)
       return regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: sentence, range: range, withTemplate: "")
   }
   ```

   And then you'd catch errors at the calling point:

   ```
   do {
       let sentence = try formatSentence(string)

       // use `sentence` here
   } catch {
       // handle error here
       print(error)
   }
   ```
3. Or, given that you know your pattern is valid, you could use `try!` knowing that it cannot fail:

   ```
   func formatSentence(_ sentence: String) -> String {
       let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\W+", options: .caseInsensitive)
       let range = NSRange(sentence.startIndex..., in: sentence)
       return regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: sentence, range: range, withTemplate: "")
   }
   ```

   And then you can just do:

   ```
   let sentence = formatSentence(string)
   ```

   You only use this last pattern if you know, with 100% confidence, that `NSRegularExpression` cannot fail given your regex pattern (such as in this situation).

---

As an aside, you might cut the Gordian knot and just use `replacingOccurrences` with `.regularExpression` option:

```
func formatSentence(_ sentence: String) -> String {
    return sentence.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\W+", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
}
```

Comment: When creating a `NSRange` you pass the `String` utf16 count `NSRange(location: 0,length: sentence.utf16.count)` or cast the `String` to `NSString` and pass its `length`

Comment: Another option is to use the new Swift 4 initializer `init<R, S>(_ region: R, in target: S) where R : RangeExpression, S : StringProtocol, R.Bound == String.Index, S.Index == String.Index` to convert from `Range` to `NSRange`: `NSRange(sentence.startIndex..<sentence.endIndex, in: sentence)`

Comment: I was focused on the throwing `NSRegularExpression` and the returning of a string, but you are correct. I've updated my examples accordingly. Like I said at the end of my answer, he really should just use `replacingOccurrences(of:with:options:)`, and eliminate all of that silliness altogether.

Answer (score -1):

Set default values at the beginning of the function like so:

```
func formatSentence(sentence:String) -> String {
   var regex = ""
   var modifiedString = "" 

   do {
       regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\W+", options: .caseInsensitive)
       modifiedString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: sentence, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0,length: sentence.count), withTemplate: "")

   } catch {
       print(error)
   }
   return modifiedString
}
```

Comment: The comment I posted at Rob’s answer applies here as well

Comment: Like the post below, this is a bad idea. Returning something valid from an error means that on the other end, you have to check if `modifiedString` is something other than empty and that gets unnecessarily complex